# Stylesheet is getting removed/deregistered automatically - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, wordpress-hook

I've put some custom code in my active child theme's `functions.php`. I'm trying to enqueue some style on a admin page. However, a style enqueued in `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook gets automatically removed and after debugging I found that its not present in the very next hook i.e. `admin_print_styles`.

Here's some code in active child theme's `functions.php` which I used for debugging purposes:

```
function debug_enqueue_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'gforms_datepicker_css', GFCommon::get_base_url() . "/css/datepicker{$min}.css", null, GFCommon::$version );
    if( wp_style_is( 'gforms_datepicker_css' ) {
        // NOTE: This runs and I am able to view the following log
        error_log( __FUNCTION__ . ': datepicker_css is enqueued.' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'debug_enqueue_admin_scripts', 11 );

function check_if_still_enqueued() {
    if( wp_style_is( 'gforms_datepicker_css', 'registered' ) ) {
        error_log( __FUNCTION__ . ' datepicker_css registered.');
    } else {
        // NOTE: It gets in this else block and following output is logged
        error_log( __FUNCTION__ . ' datepicker_css **NOT** registered.');
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'check_if_still_enqueued' );
```

I'm not deregistering the `gforms_datepicker_css` anywhere, but its getting removed maybe due to some plugin.
While debugging, I've gone further and inspected if it was deregistered by putting extra line in WordPress core class method `WP_Dependencies::remove()` located [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.6/src/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php#L262) as following.

```
public function remove( $handles ) {
    // NOTE: Check if deregistered
    error_log( __METHOD__ . ' ' . var_export( $handles, true ) );

    foreach ( (array) $handles as $handle )
        unset($this->registered[$handle]);
}
```

But I'm unable to see log output with `gforms_datepicker_css` in it from this method.

I'm unsure why the style is getting removed from enqueue list. Can anybody please help me debugging this behaviour and find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts and styles were not loading on admin pages because the **No-Conflict Mode** setting of Gravity Forms plugin was turned ON. As the setting is designed to do so:

[image]

As described in Gravity Forms [documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/enabling-no-conflict-mode/):

> To temporarily resolve the issue, go to Forms > Settings and enable No
> Conflict mode. This should stop third party scripts from writing to
> Gravity Forms administration pages and allow you to do the things you
> need.

The issue resolved after turning OFF the No-Conflict Mode.